# Upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 - showed kernel error, but rebooted and seems to be fine. Anything to be done?

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

My Ubuntu 18.10 laptop prompted the 19.04 upgrade yesterday and I went ahead and upgraded it the GUI way. Towards the end it showed errors with kernel upgrade and displayed a message that says something like a restore will be attempted or so. But once I rebooted all looked good. It shows Ubuntu 19.04 as the current version and "uname -r" is showing kernel version 5. Is there anything else to be checked or is it good?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`.

Comment: it gives this - nvidia, 418.56, 5.0.0-13-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Looks normal. No ideas. Sorry.

Comment: I think it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as known [bug 1825420](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1825420).

I have seen it during upgrade of my Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04. It showed the following warning message:

> **Could not install 'linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic'**
>
> The upgrade will continue but the 'linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
>
> triggers looping, abandoned

I ran `dpkg --configure -a` as it was recommended in warning window and do not have any issues.

Comment: I ran "dpkg --configure -a". Nothing shown as output. Hope it is fine

Comment: Check your `dkms status` and make sure your drivers appear as they should for kernel 5.0.0-13.